# How to produce output in simple C++ program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm an absolute beginner at c++. and programming in general, and I'm trying to work my way through Stroustrup's text on C++. Here is the simple program the book asks me write. The problem is when I compile and run it, nothing appears on the screen (no "enter name" or anything).
I understand keep_window_open() is used on some Windows machines, so the output window doesn't close before I get a chance to look at it, but where exactly do I place it (if indeed this is the solution)? I've tried putting it in various spots but to no avail.
Any advice is welcome.
Screenshot of the code/ Visual Studio: http://imgur.com/V3tg3tp

Comment: Visual studio has an option to choose if you want to run in console mode (what you want) or as application without console (if you implemented a userinterface and dont want the console window). You find it by rightclicking your project -> properties -> linker -> system if I recall correctly. You should check if this is set correctly.

Comment: thanks- I can't find how to alter the settings, but I'm fairly sure I set it up correctly since I followed the instructions in the textbook for that part.

Comment: @GreenRain: Create a new project, and make sure it's a console project. Start with a basic hello world program. You can find code for that everywhere, including in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>** to run the program without debugging. This runs it via a little batch file that issues a `pause` command after the program finishes, to keep its console window open. Alternatively place a breakpoint on the final `}` of `main`, and run it in the debugger, keypress **<kbd>F5</kbd>**.

Adding such stop functionality in the program itself is not a good idea: that's just annoying when you run it from the command line, and it usually needlessly makes the code non-portable.

It can however be good idea to not just explore how to run the program from the command line, but also to build it from the command line.

---

Also, as noted by Teimpz in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381631/how-to-produce-output-in-simple-c-program/35381712?noredirect=1#comment58468401_35381631), make sure that you have created a *console program project*. If you instead have created a *GUI program project*, or e.g. a *library project*, then there is no text window at all...

This can be changed in the project settings, but the easiest for a beginner is probably just to create a new project of the right kind.

Comment: thank you; I did and came up with 15 errors, pic related.

Comment: I think I should give up

Comment: Oh, is see your program is just full of errors :). You need to include <iostream> to be able to use cin and cout. Als you either have to type using namespace std or replace cin and cout with std::cin and std::cout

Comment: Also in your last cout the << is pointing the wrong direction

Comment: @Teimpz: No, Bjarne's `std_lib_facilities.h` header takes care of that. It's just for the book. The main problem Green Rain is facing is that he's not trying code from the book, but code he's devised himself. Including e.g. `cout >>`, which attempts to input from `cout`.

Comment: thank you both! I'm not a he- but anyway, this is letter for letter from the book...

Comment: I SWAPPED the direction of the arrows and now it works- thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, to run the program without it closing immediately, press `CTRL + F5` and it will run it without closing immediately.

For your errors, I noticed you had a line where it went `cout >>`. Make sure that whenever you want to output something using cout, that they go like this << and for cin, they go like this >>.

As a beginner of the level you are at, I would recommend going on to YouTube and watching [programminghelporg's](https://m.youtube.com/user/programminghelporg) videos on C++. They have really helped me learn the language.